# How to inform VIPER module about need of reloading, after another module perform task on shared service?

Tags: ios, service, viper-architecture

I'm trying to understand VIPER architecture with simple iOS tracks managing app.

I've got TracksListModule and NewTrackModule. Both with own's viewController, interactor, presenter and router. Both interactors have injected shared TracksService for fetching tracks. TracksListModule's router presents NewTrackModule's viewController which allows user to type in some track's properties. When user tap save button, NewTrackModule's interactor calls TracksService's add method then dismiss viewController to back to list.

The problem is list isn't updated after adding new track. How to inform TracksListModule's presenter (or interactor) that list needs update?